# How to get image & text value on click in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a list and I want to get image and text value using JavaScript how can i do that? right now i'm getting only selected li id.

My Code:-

```js
function reply_click()
{
    console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

```css
ul.coinList{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
ul.coinList li{ list-style:none; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px; display:flex; margin-bottom:20px; display:block;}
```

```html
<ul class="coinList">

<li id="1" onClick="reply_click();">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
<span class="coinText">one</span>
</li>

<li id="2" onClick="reply_click();">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
<span class="coinText">two</span>
</li>

</ul>
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers or running numbers as ids: https://jsfiddle.net/vt37hz8y/

Answer (score 2):

First of all the event listener can just be on the `<ul>`. And then you can find the `<li>` by using [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) from the element that was clicked (`e.target`). From there you can find the two child elements with [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```js
function reply_click(e) {
  let li_elm = e.target.closest('li');
  let img_elm = li_elm.querySelector('img');
  let span_elm = li_elm.querySelector('span');
  console.log('id:', li_elm.id, 'img:', img_elm.src, 'text:', span_elm.textContent);
}

document.querySelector('ul.coinList').addEventListener('click', reply_click);
```

```css
ul.coinList {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.coinList li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="coinList">
  <li id="1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
    <span class="coinText">one</span>
  </li>
  <li id="2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
    <span class="coinText">two</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function reply_click()
{
    if(event.currentTarget.tagName==="LI") {
      alert(event.currentTarget.id);
      alert(event.currentTarget.querySelector('img').src);
    }
}
```

```css
ul.coinList{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
ul.coinList li{ list-style:none; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px; display:flex; margin-bottom:20px; display:block;}
```

```html
<ul class="coinList">

<li id="1" onClick="reply_click();">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
<span class="coinText">one</span>
</li>

<li id="2" onClick="reply_click();">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
<span class="coinText">two</span>
</li>

</ul>
```